# python for loop mapping into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists:

```
number = [21, 44]
access = ["denied", "Try Again"]
```

I combined these two variable into one object:

```
testInput = [number, access]
```

output of `testInput`:

```
[[21, 44], ['denied', 'Try Again']]
```

Now I want to for loop through `testInput` and extract the values and map them into a key inside of a data frame.

Here is what I tried:

```
for number, access in testInput:
    df = df.append({'Access Message': access, 'Number': number},ignore_index=True)
print df
```

Output of df:

```
  Access Message  Number
0             44      21
1      Try Again  denied
```

The problem that I am facing is the value of number (44) is returning as a value of access when it shouldn't.

When I 'print number' inside the for loop I get

```
21
denied
```

What I ultimately want in `df` as an output of the for loop is

```
  Access Message  Number
0         denied      21
1      Try Again      44
```

Am I doing something wrong in my for loop? or could I have done something before the for loop differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having:

```
testInput = [number, access]
```

try:

```
testInput = zip(number, access)
```

The `zip()` method creates pairs by interleaving the two lists. So, it would give

```
 [(21, 'denied'), (44, 'Try Again')]
```

which should fit nicely with what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Access Message': access, 'Number': number})
```

which yields the desired outcome

```
  Access Message  Number
0         denied      21
1      Try Again      44
```

If you actually want to append to an existing dataframe as @Tim mentioned in the comments, you can do

```
for ni, aci in zip(number, access):
     df = df.append({'Access Message': aci, 'Number': ni}, ignore_index=True)
```

which gives (I just appended to `df` which I created above)

```
  Access Message  Number
0         denied      21
1      Try Again      44
2         denied      21
3      Try Again      44
```

But I guess what would be more efficient for huge lists is to use `concat` (as also @Wen suggests in the comments):

```
append_me = pd.DataFrame(zip(number, access)).rename(columns={0: 'Number', 1: 'Access Message'})

df = pd.concat([df, append_me])
```

which gives (I again just appended to the previous dataframe)

```
  Access Message  Number
0         denied      21
1      Try Again      44
2         denied      21
3      Try Again      44
0         denied      21
1      Try Again      44
```

Comment: It looks like they are appending to an existing dataframe - this will overwrite it.

Comment: @Tim: If I look at the desired outcome, then it does not look like it was appended to an existing dataframe but I don't know for sure...

Comment: @Tim: I edited my post based on your suggestion; now OP can decide what to use...

Comment: if append , you can consider `pd.concat`

Comment: @Wen: Yes, was just typing this when your comment appeared :)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating using two values: `for num, access in...` but your testInput is not separated that way. All the numbers are in the first item and all the access msgs are in the second item. what you want is a list of number-access **_pairs**. EG

`[(21, 'denied'), (44, 'Try Again'), (99, 'someMessage') ...]`

try

`pairs = zip(testInput[0], testInput[1])`

this takes the first item in each list (`testInput[0]` and `testInput[1]`) and matches them together. So the first number gets put into a tuple with the first access, the second num with second access... and so on.

Then run `pairs` through for loop

```
for number, access in pairs:
    df = df.append({'Access Message': access, 'Number': number},ignore_index=True)
print df
```